# Can we add a dropdown attribute of different colors in topmenu?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to show a dropdown menu of different colors for specific products in topmenu of product page.
So that if the admin adds one color attribute of a specific product, it will automatically show in topmenu of product page.

Comment: Where are you storing color attribute added by admin for specific product? Is this part of product data?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension which solves ur problem. It works fine and I am using it.. 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-9787.html It displays color near to product price in product view page. You can modify as u required..